# Tasks are moved to removed state in Airflow when they are queued and not restored

Tags: airflow

When task instances marked with State.REMOVED state in Airflow? When I am dynamically generating tasks using for loop, after execution of one of the tasks other tasks are getting removed and not restored back again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its better to have a Airflow DAG which has constant/stable definition i.e. tasks of the DAG are not changing when its executing. Problem with dynamic DAG is, its definition/tasks executed might change when the DAG is already executing. If in any case there is need of dynamic DAG, the min_file_process_interval should be set to value which is higher than execution time of the DAG so that new definition is not fetched during current execution.

Answer (score 5):

The `REMOVED` state is applied by the `airflow.models.DagRun:verify_integrity` method when it finds a `task_id` in the database that no longer exists on the associated `DAG` object. This can certainly happen if you're dynamically building tasks with different `task_id` values.

Comment: Yes, I am creating tasks with different task_id as it's more readable when I see the pipeline running, as all tasks are performing same task with different params. Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: One more thing is when I ran my code keeping the same task_id value, I am getting error saying this task is already been registered to parent task.

Comment: Hi Joeb, thanks for your help here. The actual issue was with my code and airflow configs. I was updating the metadata about the status of my tasks in the database which is responsible to create the tasks. And as the dag name is not changed it was updating the tasks ; and also as min_file_process_interval was 60 seconds(which is very less as my tasks taking more than 20-30 mins to complete) and hence in between DAG definition was getting refreshed.

Comment: @SwapnilDengale we are also facing same issue, what was your fix for that.

Comment: Did you find any solution? @SwapnilDengale

Comment: @SwapnilDengale I am also facing the similar issue while looping and creating the task_id dynamically using  for loop. Can you please let us know how did you resolve the issue.

Comment: Any solution for this one?

Comment: Its better to have DAG which has constant/stable definition. Problem with dynamic DAG is its definition/tasks executed might change when the DAG is already executing. If in any case there is need of dynamic DAG, the min_file_process_interval should be set to value which is higher than execution time of the DAG so that new definition is not fetched during current execution.